# Function that returns true or false if certain conditions are met?

Tags: python

So a user will input a string value in binary format. i.e. '01000001'

I want to check the value they enter to see if it:

> 1. has only eight characters.
> 2. is a string type
> 3. and only contains '0's or '1's

preferably to be done with a function that takes in the user value so that i can call it whenever.  Returns false if conditions are not met.

this is what i came up with so far...

```
 size = len(teststring)
 teststring = '11111111'

 def typecheck(value):
    if type(user_input) == type(teststring) and len(user_input) == size and contains only 1 | 0
    return
```

Comment: Will the user input come from the command line? If so, it will be a string by default.

Comment: `def typecheck(value): return isinstance(value, str) and len(value) == 8 == (value.count('0') + value.count('1'))`

Comment: user input comes from input call. Using python IDE shell thing. If that's what you mean, then that's good to know. But i would still like to check see if it is a string, just in case

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte It will be a string if you use the input function. It would be a redundant to test it because we know the input function returns a string.

Comment: @Darwin Ah i get you now. Good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use regex matching here:

```
reg = re.compile(r'^[01]{8}$')

def typecheck(value):
    return isinstance(value, str) and bool(reg.match(value))
```

Or since you want to check for binary format number, how about converting it to `int` with base 2, and see if it's a valid conversion:

```
def typecheck(value):
    try:
        return len(value) == 8 and bool(int(value, 2))
    except TypeError, ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: just two points don't use bare except it will catch everything and there is no need to check `isinstance(value, str)` since `len` will throw exception if you are checking on an integer

Answer (score 4):

No need for regex

You could use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and strip all `1` and `0` from end and beginning and check.

**Code:**

```
check = "11101110"

if isinstance(check,str) and len(check)==8 and check.strip("01")=='':
    print "yes"
```

**Output:**

```
yes
```

Comment: BTW, I think `isinstance(check,str)`  is useless here. Because if it's not string object, `check.strip("01")` will raise `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'` (for example it's a list).

Comment: @KevinGuan yes but I have not catching the exception like rohit is doing so it would stop the program.

Comment: Ah, fine. Just a note about if you remove `isinstance()` in this case and OP doesn't care about the program keeping running or not, the program'll also not print `yes` but an error instead :).

Comment: yes if they want they could do that or add a `try catch` :)

Comment: `and not check.strip("01")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham are you suggesting to convert `check.strip("01")==''` to  `not check.strip("01")`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with one `if` statement. If the regex doesn't find a match it will return `None` which evaluates to `False` in a truth test.

```
import re

def check_input(user_input):
    if not re.match(r'^[01]{8}$', user_input):
        it doesn't meet requirements do something
```